# Can I forge the HTTP HOST-header param in order to fake a request to a non-mapped subdomain?

Tags: http, iis, http-headers, fiddler

Scenario: I want a staging environment at a customer's site. The customer owns www.example.com. I want to map the site to staging.example.com reachable from the outside, but I haven't got time to wait for the bureaucracy surrounding either the purchase of the new subdomain or opening of secondary HTTP ports.

Assumption: If I spoof the HTTP Header param `Host` to be `staging.example.com` on the client side, but actually make the request to the IP of `www.example.com`, IIS will redirect the request to the configured site for `staging.example.com`. Am I right?

So is there any client tool that can help me with that? I'm fairly famailiar with Fiddler, but it seem to override my rewrites of the host parameter. Also I would need to configure it to do it for every request, not just one, to make it trivial to test.

Are there simpler solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Inside Fiddler, by clicking `Tools > HOSTS` and you can send all traffic targeting one site, e.g. `dev.example.com` to the IP of your choice. The target site (namely `dev.example.com`) doesn't need to exist at all in this case. Your client (e.g. the browser) has no idea that Fiddler is retargeting the traffic, it just thinks that it is talking to `dev.example.com`.

If you have the Fiddler book, check out the *Retargeting Traffic* section for many other ways to retarget traffic.